# Merge between 2 nested dictionaries and obtain single dict

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-11

I know there are similar question about this. I tried searching example and answer but I don't have a clear solution. I am stuck at this. I have 2 nested dictionaries and I want to merge it into single dict. It is in JSON version but running in python too is fine.

```
x = {'folders': [
{'id': 124, 'name': 'Leads', 'totalBlacklisted': 0, 'uniqueSubscribers': 0, 'totalSubscribers': 0}, 
{'id': 123, 'name': 'Alumni', 'totalBlacklisted': 0, 'uniqueSubscribers': 0, 'totalSubscribers': 0}, 
]}
y = {'folders':[{'id': 124,'name':'Leads'}, {'id': 121,'name': 'Member'},{'id':123,'name':'Alumni'}]}
```

What I want:

```
result = {'folders': [
{'id': 124, 'name': 'Leads', 'totalBlacklisted': 0, 'uniqueSubscribers': 0, 'totalSubscribers': 0}, 
{'id': 123, 'name': 'Alumni', 'totalBlacklisted': 0, 'uniqueSubscribers': 0, 'totalSubscribers': 0},
{'id': 121, 'name': 'Member'} 
]}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is to group the elements we consider identical by some key with `groupby`, which the tuple `(x[id] , x[name])`, and then combine all excess elements other than our key per group with `ChainMap`.

```py
from pprint import pprint
from itertools import groupby
from collections import ChainMap

a = {
    'folders': [
        { 'id': 124, 'name': 'Leads',  'totalBlacklisted': 0, 'uniqueSubscribers': 0, 'totalSubscribers': 0 }, 
        { 'id': 123, 'name': 'Alumni', 'totalBlacklisted': 0, 'uniqueSubscribers': 0, 'totalSubscribers': 0 }, 
    ]
}

b = {
    'folders': [
        { 'id': 124, 'name': 'Leads'  },
        { 'id': 121, 'name': 'Member' },
        { 'id': 123, 'name': 'Alumni' }
    ]
}

def key(x):
    return (x['id'], x['name'])

def merge(a, b, key):
    c = a + b
    groups = groupby(sorted(c, key=key), key=key)
    merged = [dict(ChainMap(*g)) for _, g in groups]
    return merged
```

```
pprint({'folders': merge(a['folders'], b['folders'], key=key)})
> {'folders': [{'id': 121, 'name': 'Member'},
               {'id': 123,
                'name': 'Alumni',
                'totalBlacklisted': 0,
                'totalSubscribers': 0,
                'uniqueSubscribers': 0},
               {'id': 124,
                'name': 'Leads',
                'totalBlacklisted': 0,
                'totalSubscribers': 0,
                'uniqueSubscribers': 0}]}
```

If you want to look at the output of `groupby`, run this modified merge function:

```
def merge(a, b, key):
    c = a + b
    groups = groupby(sorted(c, key=key), key=key)
    merged = [(k, list(g)) for k, g in groups]
    return merged
```

Comment: Yes this is the best answer that I can find. Thank you so much for replying and answering correctly. You made my day @kluvin.

Comment: Hi sorry for bothering you again. I want to ask if I want to obtain only the new value that didn't merged meaning `{'id': 121, 'name': 'Member'}` value only. How can I modify your code so `{'id': 121, 'name': 'Member'}` emerge. Thanks

Comment: @RichardAngga I think the answer to that depends a little on the heuristic by which you choose the excess. ChainMap overwrites any successive properties, and it doesn't remember anything about that. So what you want to do is to look at everything groupby gets and then think a little about exactly that.

Since I don't know what your data generally looks like I could tell you several ways to do this, and I wouldn't know which one is generally correct.

See the updated answer for some pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add them and condition on the dictionary whose values you want to keep incase of conflicting ids:

```
x['folders']+[dic for dic in y['folders'] if dic['id'] not in [dic['id'] for dic in x['folders']]]
```

results in:

```
[{'id': 124,
  'name': 'Leads',
  'totalBlacklisted': 0,
  'uniqueSubscribers': 0,
  'totalSubscribers': 0},
 {'id': 123,
  'name': 'Alumni',
  'totalBlacklisted': 0,
  'uniqueSubscribers': 0,
  'totalSubscribers': 0},
 {'id': 121, 'name': 'Member'}]
```

Comment: Hi Hamza. Thanks for replying.Okay, I tried using it in (https://trinket.io/python/33c83f08c9) but the result display 2 `'name' Alumni` value. No `'name' Member` value. Let me check again if I am missing a code.

Comment: Keep in mind that it considers ids for de duplication criteria. You must have mistakenly assign same ID to different names. Check this again. You can also put the same dictionaries you used in the question to reproduce the same result

Comment: Alternatively you can change 'id' to 'name' if that's your criteria

Comment: Hi @Hamza . No it is the correct IDs between two dicts. And I change the id to names too, but the result is same. Two `Alumni` value and one `Leads`, no `Member`. Perhaps it needs to differentiate the list. But thanks again for trying mate. Your answer is simple in one line and I want to use it next time. Cheers